# How to integrate Mapbox iOS framework into Kotlin native

Tags: mapbox, kotlin-native

I'm trying to integrate Mapbox's frameworks into my Kotlin multiplatform library. But I'm getting a compile error with the cinterop portion.

First problem was with the compile step with MapboxMobileEvents framework.  The `MapboxMobileEvents.h` has import statements referring to a `MapboxMobileEvents` directory that doesn't exist.  I created a symbolic link to get around that.

After that I'm getting an error from clang.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: clang_parseTranslationUnit2 failed with CXError_ASTReadError;
sourceFile = /var/folders/vj/mvxq9qtn1r9_8x2c7zyx04_m0000gn/T/tmp6661284981682757951tmp8536987580934998728.m
arguments = -fmodules -isystem /Users/mkrussel/.konan/dependencies/clang-llvm-apple-8.0.0-darwin-macos/lib/clang/8.0.0/include -B/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin -fno-stack-protector -stdlib=libc++ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.5.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -O2 -I/Users/mkrussel/pangea/mapbox-native/pangea-mapbox/frameworks/MapboxMobileEvents.framework/Headers -fobjc-arc -include-pch /var/folders/vj/mvxq9qtn1r9_8x2c7zyx04_m0000gn/T/tmp1085765932502683439.pch -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -ferror-limit=0
```

The `tmp6661284981682757951tmp8536987580934998728.m` name changes on every build, but the file is always empty, which is what I assume is causing the problem.

What I cannot figure out is what causes the file to be empty.

Did I configure the cinterop wrong?

Is the Kotlin plugin broken?

Is something with the Mapbox frameworks incompatible with Kotlin native?

My gradle file looks like

```
iOSTarget("ios") {
   compilations {
         @Suppress("UNUSED_VARIABLE")
         val main by getting {
             kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xobjc-generics")

             val frameworksDir = "$projectDir/frameworks"
             cinterops(Action {
               val mapboxEvents by creating {
                   defFile("$frameworksDir/mapbox-events.def")

                   includeDirs.allHeaders("$frameworksDir/MapboxMobileEvents.framework/Headers")
               }
             })

             cinterops(Action {
                val mapbox by creating {
                    defFile("$frameworksDir/mapbox.def")
                    includeDirs.allHeaders("$frameworksDir/Mapbox.framework/Headers")
                }
             })
        }
    }
}
```

mapbox-events.def

```
package = framework.mapbox.events
language = Objective-C
headers = MapboxMobileEvents.h
headersFilter = **

compilerOpts = -F/Users/mkrussel/pangea/mapbox-native/pangea-mapbox/frameworks -framework MapboxMobileEvents -fmodules
linkerOpts = -F/Users/mkrussel/pangea/mapbox-native/pangea-mapbox/frameworks -framework MapboxMobileEvents
```

mapbox.def

```
package = framework.mapbox
language = Objective-C
headers = Mapbox.h
headersFilter = **

compilerOpts = -F/Users/mkrussel/pangea/mapbox-native/pangea-mapbox/frameworks -framework Mapbox -fmodules
linkerOpts = -F/Users/mkrussel/pangea/mapbox-native/pangea-mapbox/frameworks -framework Mapbox
```

Using full path names in the `.def` files to make sure that there's no relative path problems.
Trying to use just one of the `mapbox.def` or the `mapbox-events.def` file still produces the same error.

Using:

- Kotlin version 1.3.72
- Xcode version 11.5 (11E608c)

Tried this also, and I get the same failure.

```
    iOSTarget("ios") {
        val frameworksDir = "$projectDir/frameworks"
        compilations {
            @Suppress("UNUSED_VARIABLE")
            val main by getting {
                kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xobjc-generics")

                cinterops(Action {
                    val mapboxEvents by creating {
                        defFile("$frameworksDir/mapbox-events.def")
                        packageName("com.mapbox.events")
                        header("$frameworksDir/MapboxMobileEvents.framework/Headers/MapboxMobileEvents.h")

                        compilerOpts("-fmodules")
                        includeDirs.allHeaders("$frameworksDir/MapboxMobileEvents.framework/Headers")
                    }
                })

                cinterops(Action {
                    val mapbox by creating {
                        defFile("$frameworksDir/mapbox.def")
                        packageName("com.mapbox")
                        header("$frameworksDir/Mapbox.framework/Headers/Mapbox.h")
                        compilerOpts("-fmodules")
                        includeDirs.allHeaders("$frameworksDir/Mapbox.framework/Headers")
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        binaries {
            executable {
                linkerOpts = mutableListOf("-F$frameworksDir", "-framework", "Mapbox", "-framework", "MapboxMobileEvents")
            }

        }
    }
```

mapbox-event.def

```
language = Objective-C
```

mapbox.def

```
language = Objective-C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got this to work.

mapbox.def

```
language = Objective-C
modules = Mapbox
linkerOpts = -framework Mapbox
```

in build.gradle.kts

```
kotlin {
    ios {
        val frameworkLocation = File(rootDir, "native/TestApp/Pods/Mapbox-iOS-SDK/dynamic/").absolutePath
        val frameworks = "-F$frameworkLocation"
        compilations {
            @Suppress("UNUSED_VARIABLE")
            val main by getting {
                cinterops {
                    val mapbox by creating {
                        defFile = File("$projectDir/libs/mapbox.def")
                        packageName("com.mapbox")
                        compilerOpts(frameworks)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        binaries.matching { it is org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.Framework }
            .configureEach {
                val framework = this as org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.Framework
                framework.linkerOpts(frameworks)
            }
    }
}
```

Seems like one of the big pieces I was missing was the modules line

Answer (score 0):

I've played with those frameworks a bit and here goes what I've found.
You don't need those `compilerOpts` in the `.def` file. This option is for the cinterop tool, not the final binary compilation. Options you're setting here should probably go to the `kotlin.binaries.framework` block of the Gradle script. More info can be found in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#cinterop-support).

---

UPD: This advice is not completely correct, as it fixes the generation of bindings only for the Mapbox framework. The problem is that the `cinterop` tool has an issue with `-fmodules` compiler flag. This flag is important for the MapboxMobileEvents framework as it relies on the `@import` syntax when it uses Foundation and CoreFoundation frameworks. 
Please subscribe to the YouTrack issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39120). I'll make an update here when it will be fixed.

Comment: Tried removing the options from the `.def` files as suggested.  Simplified the `complierOpts`, but I still get the same failure.

Without the "-fmodules" in the cinterops, I get a compiler error about use of import keyword

Comment: Thanks for creating the ticket with JetBrains.